# Visual Studio sizeof illegal operand

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, visual-c++, sizeof

I am currently porting a program developed on Linux to Win32. Amongst other problems, I have one that is pretty weird.
A header file contains something like this:

```
namespace Networking {
  struct  MetaStruct
  {
    int   iDataType;
    int   iDataSize;
    void* pData;
  };

  const int MetaStructSize = sizeof(MetaStruct) - sizeof(MetaStruct::pData);
};
```

This compiles fine on fine on Linux, but I get this error when compiling for Win32 using VS2010:
`Networking.hpp(50): error C2070: '': illegal sizeof operand`

I tried adding the `Networking::` before `MetaStruct` but it doesn't change anything. The weird thing is VS2010 gives me the correct value of the `sizeof` when I hover it with the mouse, but won't compile it. Why?

Comment: Try `sizeof(decltype(std::declval<MetaStruct>().pdata))`, from `<type_traits>`.

Comment: @BoPersson: I imagine the point of the question was how to express this without repeating the type! :-) (A DRY solution, if you will.)

Comment: Odd indeed. Can you remove the other sizeof just to be sure we are looking at the right one?

Comment: @Kerrek - That's why I have a smiley. My code solves the problem in a quarter of your code size. And it's pretty obvious that he wants the size of the struct without the pointer.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Are you really looking for `offsetof(MetaStruct, pData)` or even `void*(MetaStruct::*p) = &MetaStruct::pData;`

Comment: I am only looking for the size of the structure except for the size of the data pointer in order to send it via socket. But the problem is solved now :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In C++03 There are two forms of sizeof expressions (see ISO/IEC 14882:2003 5.3.3 [expr.sizeof]).

```
sizeof unary-expression
sizeof ( type-id )
```

`MetaStruct::pData` is neither a valid expression (resolving to an object type) nor the name of a type.

You would have to do

```
sizeof( void* )
```

or

```
sizeof MetaStruct().pData
```

---

Update: Thanks to @hvd who points out that this should actually be legal in C++11 now.

You can now use an *id-expression* that refers to a non-static member of a class in contexts where it isn't evaluated. Evidently this isn't supported by VS2010.

There's also a new form of `sizeof` in C++11: `sizeof ... ( identifier )` but that's not relevant here.

Comment: So why *is* the OP's original version compilable with GCC?

Comment: The second is problematic for types with no default constructor. `sizeof ((MetaStruct*)0)->pData` is ugly, but would work in that case.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: True, I was just choosing the simplest expression that would work for the question as asked.

Comment: Does your solution work if there is no accessible default constructor?

Comment: Thanks, although as Kerrek SB I'm wondering why does `sizeof(MetaStruct::pData)` work with GCC.

Comment: `sizeof(MetaStruct::pData)` is allowed in C++11. [expr.prim.general]: "An id-expression that denotes a non-static data member or non-static member function of a class can only be used: [...], or -- if that id-expression denotes a non-static data member and it appears in an unevaluated operand."

Comment: @hvd: Interesting, I didn't know that. My gcc seems to be allowing it even in `-std=c++98 -pedantic` mode.

Comment: @CharlesBailey Also interesting, I think that's a bug. It was allowed well after the previous update of the C++ standard, and required a diagnostic before that. http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#613